# How can I use the ControlPaint.DrawBorder method to modifiy the border color of a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, combobox, gdi+

I have a requirement to set the border color of the Combobox control.
I've searched Google for a sample code that was implementing `ControlPaint.Drawborder`.
What I found is not ideal. The color of the border is not modified.
In the code below, you'll see two key functions, `WndProc` and `PaintControlBorder()`, which are used to receive the underlying windows events and handle them.
The latter is used to draw the border of the control. After debugging with Visual Studio, I found that the code in the `PaintControlBorder()` function was executed.

Why is the border color not changing?

```
[ToolboxItem(true)]
public class ModifiedComboBox : ComboBox
{
    new public System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode DrawMode { get; set; }
    public Color HighlightColor { get; set; } //set select item highlight color 
    private IntPtr hDC;
    private Graphics gdc;
    private const int WM_ERASEBKGND = 0x14; // some windows message id 
    private const int WM_PAINT = 0xF;
    private const int WM_NC_PAINT = 0x85;
    private const int WM_PRINTCLIENT = 0x318;
    private const int WM_MOUSEHOVER = 0x2A1;
    private const int WM_MOUSELEAVE = 0x2A3;

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);
    private Rectangle rectale;

    public ModifiedComboBox()
    {
        hDC = GetDC(Handle);
        gdc = Graphics.FromHdc(hDC);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
        base.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        this.HighlightColor = Color.Gray;
        this.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(AdvancedComboBox_DrawItem); //t bind draw item handler

        rectale = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
    }

    public void AdvancedComboBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index < 0)
            return;

        ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(HighlightColor), e.Bounds);
            //e.Graphics.DrawString(combo.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(combo.BackColor), new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));

            e.Graphics.DrawString(combo.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(combo.ForeColor), new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(combo.BackColor), e.Bounds);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(combo.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(combo.ForeColor), new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
        }
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)// windows message handler
    {
        if (this.DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.Simple)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            return;
        }

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_NC_PAINT:
                break;
            case WM_PAINT:
                base.WndProc(ref m);

                PaintControlBorder();
                break;
            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
    private void PaintControlBorder()
    {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(gdc, this.ClientRectangle, Color.Orange, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you delete your recent question?

Comment: @Enigmativity This problem seems to be a bad question. If I ask some questions, no one will reply. Stackoverflow will give me a bad evaluation, I will not be able to  ask any more questions.

Comment: We're here to help you to make a good question. You don't get banned from asking questions. We're here to help.,

Comment: thankyou so much! I won't stop asking questions, I will try to make some better questions. @Enigmativity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Forms, you never store the Graphics object of a Control.
You can use the one provided by one of the Graphics methods (Paint, DrawItem etc.) or, like in this case, you create a new one when required and you dispose of it right after.
In this example, implicitly, enclosing the Graphics object creation in an `using` block.

This is a simple example, using [ControlPaint.DrawBorder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawborder), that show how draw a border around a ComboBox control, using a Graphics object derived from the control Handle ([`Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromhwnd)) on a [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-paint) message received overriding the control's [WndProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc).

The sample Custom Control exposes a public Property, **`BorderColor`**, which allows to change the color of the border.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerCategory("Code")]
class ComboSimpleBorder : ComboBox
{
    private const int WM_PAINT = 0xF;
    private Color m_BorderColor = Color.Red;

    public ComboSimpleBorder() { }

    [Browsable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Category("Appearance")]
    [Description("Get or Set the Color of the Control's border")]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Red")]
    public Color BorderColor 
    {
        get => m_BorderColor;
        set { m_BorderColor = value; Invalidate(); }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT) {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle)) {
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, ClientRectangle, m_BorderColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
            }
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is great and completely solves my problem. thank you very much!